# How to count letter of each word

Tags: java, android, string, int, cpu-word

I was wondering how I would write a method to count the number of words and  number of each word letters
for example  if input is  "The Blue Sky" in return i take something that show me there was 3 words 3 letter 4 letter 3 letter

i'v found this code already

```
public static int countWords(String s){

    int wordCount = 0;

    boolean word = false;
    int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // if the char is a letter, word = true.
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
            word = true;
            // if char isn't a letter and there have been letters before,
            // counter goes up.
        } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && word) {
            wordCount++;
            word = false;
            // last word of String; if it doesn't end with a non letter, it
            // wouldn't count without this.
        } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

I really appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Comment: I'd split the string at a space with `s.split(" ")`. You can get the amount of words with `s.split(" ").length` and the length of individuals with `for(String x : s.split(" ")){ System.out.println(x.length()); }

Comment: what is the prob with the above code??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1 - Find the number of words in the sentence using the space separator.**

```
 String CurrentString = "How Are You";
    String[] separated = CurrentString.split(" ");
    String sResultString="";
    int iWordCount = separated.length;
    sResultString = iWordCount +" words";
```

**Step 2 - Find letter count in each word.**

```
    for(int i=0;i<separated.length;i++)
    {
    String s = separated[i];
    sResultString = sResultString + s.length + " letters ";
    }

// Print sResultString
```

Comment: Tank you  it was exactly what i needed .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm.
You should be able to use the Java String.split() function to break up the string by spaces " ".
That should give you an array that contains each word.  Then it is simply finding the length of each word.

Answer (score 0):

to count words this might help

```
  public static int countWords(String str)
        {
            int count = 1;
            for (int i=0;i<=str.length()-1;i++)
            {
                if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
            String sentence = in.nextline();
            System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code-

```
   public void countWordsLetters(String s){
        String str[]=s.split(" ");
        System.out.println("No. of words in string::"+str.length);
        for (int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            System.out.println("No of letters in "+i+" word "+str[i].length());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, most of the above answers are correct but nobody considered the whitespace while counting the characters in String. Hope you can also include that.

```
          for(int j=0;j<name.length();j++){ //here is name is my string

          if(Character.isWhitespace(name.charAt(j))){

            }else{
                count+=1;
            }

      }
      System.out.println("The word count is "+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer thanks to Sahil Nagpal for the inspiration:

```
package exercise;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class method_letter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter any string");
    String s=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("the letter count :"+lettercount(s));

}
public static int lettercount (String s) {
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))){

        }else {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}